# Hardware raid, LVM and KVM cache policy

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cache, lvm, raid-controller, virtio

I have a question about right cache policy for KVM using LVM and hardware raid-controller.

So from the bottom:
1. We have LSI RAID controller 9260, 512Mb cache and BBU. Later we also will have CacheCade(SSD Drive as a cache) license and will use SSD.
Now controller have virtual drives configured with "write back" and "Disak cache policy:disabled"

2. Virtual drive presented to LVM. LVM as i know doesn't have any cache policy.
3. On KVM level - disk attacehd to guest system as virtio-scsi and cache policy set to writethrough.

So question is how to get maximum drive speed in guest and not afraid of power shutdown.

I suppose if i will set virtio-scsi drive policy to "write-back" KVM will use host memory for caching guest io.

So i want to ask if we have optimum configuration now?

Guest system is Windows Server 2012R2 and NTFS. Host system is Centos 6.7 updated.

Comment: What did your tests tell you?

Comment: I cant test power shutdown. Now we dont have Windows 2012R2 guest on host system, but other virtuals are running. But we have applied SSD and CacheCade - so there is a strange behavior now, i suppose raid-controller cache not working now.